# Show cropped image

Tags: php, crop, php-gd

I'm using a script that helps users to upload their profile images then to crop them to choose the convenient position 
I have a problem with PNG & GIF images they aren't shown 
This is the crop file code please modify it in order to make it able to show the PNG , JPF and GIF images

```
<?php
 sleep(1);
 $url = $_GET['url'];
 $type = $_GET['type'];
 if ($type='jpg') {
    if(file_exists($url) AND preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\/_\-.]+$/i',$url)){
$width  =   (isset($_GET['width'])  AND preg_match('/^[0-9]{2,}$/', $_GET['width']))    ? $_GET['width']    : 300;
$height =   (isset($_GET['height']) AND preg_match('/^[0-9]{2,}$/', $_GET['height']))   ? $_GET['height']   : 300;
$left   =   (isset($_GET['left'])   AND is_numeric($_GET['left']))  ? $_GET['left']     : 0;
$top    =   (isset($_GET['top'])    AND is_numeric($_GET['top']))       ? $_GET['top']      : 0;
header ("Content-type: image/jpg");
$src    =   @imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
$im     =   @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopy($im,$src,0,0,-$left,-$top,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($im,"",300);
imagedestroy($im);}}

    elseif ($type='png') {

     if(file_exists($url) AND preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\/_\-.]+$/i',$url)){
$width  =   (isset($_GET['width'])  AND preg_match('/^[0-9]{2,}$/', $_GET['width']))    ? $_GET['width']    : 300;
$height =   (isset($_GET['height']) AND preg_match('/^[0-9]{2,}$/', $_GET['height']))   ? $_GET['height']   : 300;
$left   =   (isset($_GET['left'])   AND is_numeric($_GET['left']))  ? $_GET['left']     : 0;
$top    =   (isset($_GET['top'])    AND is_numeric($_GET['top']))       ? $_GET['top']      : 0;
header ("Content-type: image/png");
$src    =   @imagecreatefrompng($url);
$im     =   @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopy($im,$src,0,0,-$left,-$top,$width,$height);
imagepng($im,"",300);
imagedestroy($im);
     }
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: look into `filter_var` please and adopt a proper coding style.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the format of the input file, then call the supported functions.

If the input file is a jpeg, call `imagecreatefromjpeg` and `imagejpeg`.
If the input file is a png, call `imagecreatefrompng` and `imagepng`.
If the input file is a gif, call `imagecreatefromjpeg` and `imagegif`.

Comment: Or use `imagecreatefromstring()` from the image data, and use one of the `imageTYPE()` functions after determining its type.

Comment: Doesn't work 
I added $type = $_GET['type']; and elseif ($type = 'png')

Comment: What is the value of $_GET['type']? Are you 100% sure it is correct? Also, you should use `switch(){}` instead of huge `elseif` blocks.

Comment: $_GET['type'] will get the extension of the image.This is the full url : data/result_crop_img.php?tr=crop.php?url=img_upload_profile/6348877.jpg&top=0&left=-175&type=png

Comment: Remove the `Content-Type` header and see if it outputs an error.

Comment: same problem mate ...
it doesn't show an error but the image is only not shown